# Finding MODE Iterating through FOR Loop for multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, math

**Desired:**

I have multiple arrays of players, `roundWinners`, being iterated through in a FOR loop.  For each array, I need the MODE of the array (the most frequently occurring value) assigned to a new variable `winner`.

I am lost as to where to start, so I ask what is the most efficient way to go about accomplishing this?

**Example:**

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
var roundWinners[0] = ["Joe", "Joe", "Bob", "Sue"]
var winner[0] ="Joe";

var roundWinners[1] = ["Joe", "Sue", "Bob", "Sue"]
var winner[1] ="Sue";

var roundWinners[2] = ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Sue"]
var winner[2] ="Bob";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the loop, create an object.

```
    var ArrMode = {};
```

Then, on each iteration, take the name, and, using it as a property name, see if the object has a property of that name. If so, increment the value of that property.

If not, *add* that property, setting its value to 1.

After processing the array, then process the object, using a simple replace-if-greater test. Each time you make a replacement, hold the name of that property as the winner.

Once you have processed the whole object, the property name you are holding is the name of the winner.

Comment: Could you post an example of this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually have an answer

One person posted this as a way to iterate through the properties of a JS object, when you do not know the property names at design time:

```
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

You can add a property to a JS object at any time, using:

```
    obj[theName] = theVal; // the name’d be a string, theVal’d be anything
    // Like:
    var theName = "John";
    obj[theName] = 1;
```

So, you would create an empty object before the loop with a name (like, say "modes"), but no properties

```
    var modes = {};
```

Then, in each iteration over the array, iterate through the object's properties, checking the name of the properties against the current name in the array.

If found, then use:

```
    modes[arr[i]]++;
```

If not found, then use

```
    modes[arr[i]] = 1;
```

After the iterating over the array, iterate over the object's properties, checking their values, and 'remembering' the name and value of the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

**Working:**

```
//Mode Calc
function mode( arr ) {
    if ( !Array.isArray( arr ) ) {
        throw new TypeError( 'mode()::invalid input argument. Must provide an array.' );
    }
    var len = arr.length,
        count = {},
        max = 0,
        vals = [],
        val;

    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        val = arr[ i ];
        if ( !count[ val ] ) {
            count[ val ] = 0;
        }
        count[ val ] += 1;
        if ( count[ val ] === max ) {
            vals.push( val );
        } else {
            max = count[ val ];
            vals = [ val ];
        }
    }
    return vals.sort( function sort( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    });
} // end FUNCTION mode()

for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
winner = ( mode( roundWinners[i] ) );
}
```